# Xerces C++ DTD validation always fails

Tags: c++, validation, dtd, xerces

I am trying to validate some XML with an external DTD file using Xerces C++. Unfortunately, the validation fails when it shouldn't, I get the error message "XmlErrorHandler : XML error in line 3 at column 11: Unknown element 'c'".

I am trying to validate the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<c>
    <p>
        <r>...</r>
        <g>...</g>
        <b>...</b>
    </p>
    <s>
        <r>...</r>
        <g>...</g>
        <b>...</b>
    </s>
    <t>
        <r>...</r>
        <g>...</g>
        <b>...</b>
    </t>
    <l0>...</l0>
    <l1>...</l1>
    <l2>...</l2>
</c>
```

with the following DTD (located at C:\mydtd.dtd):

```
<!ELEMENT c (p, s, t, l0, l1, l2)>
<!ELEMENT p (r, g, b)>
<!ELEMENT s (r, g, b)>
<!ELEMENT t (r, g, b)>
<!ELEMENT r (#CDATA)>
<!ELEMENT g (#CDATA)>
<!ELEMENT b (#CDATA)>
<!ELEMENT l0 (#CDATA)>
<!ELEMENT l1 (#CDATA)>
<!ELEMENT l2 (#CDATA)>
```

This is the code where the parser is loaded:

```
m_pkXmlParser = XMLReaderFactory::createXMLReader();
m_pkXmlParser->loadGrammar("C:\\mydtd.dtd", Grammar::DTDGrammarType);
m_pkXmlParseHandler = new XmlParseHandler;
m_pkXmlErrorHandler = new XmlErrorHandler;
m_pkEntityResolver = new XmlEntityResolver;
m_pkXmlParser->setContentHandler(m_pkXmlParseHandler);
m_pkXmlParser->setErrorHandler(m_pkXmlErrorHandler);
m_pkXmlParser->setEntityResolver(m_pkEntityResolver);
```

Any help why the validation fails is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whoever voted for this question cost me my "Tumbleweed" badge ;) Oh well, for some reason, this problem vanished after having two parser objects: One for validation, one for content parsing. Good enough for me.